# React render function within a function in JSX?

Tags: reactjs

In my component's render function I'm calling anouther function with markup. So far so good.

```
renderEquipmentOptions() {
  return (
    <div className="form-check">
      <label className="form-check-label">
        <input className="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value=""/>
        Nothing
      </label>
    </div>
  )
}
```

However now I want to add a map to this function to generate additional markup.

```
renderEquipmentOptions() {
  const render = this.props.equipment.map((item, i) => {
    return (
      <div key={i} className="form-check form-check-inline">
        <label className="form-check-label">
          <input className="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value=""/>
          {item}
        </label>
      </div>
    )
  });

  return (
    <div className="form-check">
      <label className="form-check-label">
        <input className="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value=""/>
        Nothing
      </label>
    </div>
    {this.render()}
  )
}
```

This doesn't work. It seems you cant wrap a function in {} and call it. Is this because its a function within a function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work because you are trying to return multiple elements from the function without returning them as an array. Also `render` is not a function in your case but a `variable`

change your code to return an array like

```
renderEquipmentOptions() {
  const render = this.props.equipment.map((item, i) => {
    return (
      <div key={i} className="form-check form-check-inline">
        <label className="form-check-label">
          <input className="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value=""/>
          {item}
        </label>
      </div>
    )
  });

  return (
    [<div className="form-check">
      <label className="form-check-label">
        <input className="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value=""/>
        Nothing
      </label>
    </div>,
    ...render
    ]
  )
}
```

Comment: Thats strange, I am on version 16

Comment: Sorry for not explaining it correctly. In React 16 you can return multiple elements from the components render function by returning an array, however from a function you can still return an array of elements even if you are using a lesser version. This way is called JSX syntactic sugar.